# BMO$2$ $2021$ Q$3$: Prove AI and KD meet on the circumcircle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I’m stuck on question $3$ from BMO$2$ $2021$ (https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo2-2021.pdf)

So the first observation I’ve made is that K is the intersection of the circle with diameter AI with $\Gamma$ (converse of Thales)

From there the only idea that came to me was to somehow try and leverage symmetry along the line AIT (where T is the midpoint of the arc BC), since the incircle and the circle with diameter AI are symmetric along here and AC and AB are each others reflections in this way.

My diagram (r denotes reflection in AT): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAjwd.jpg

And I thought it would be easier to prove the equivalent result that K D and T are colinear (here I define T as the midpoint of the arc BC or equivalently the intersection of AI and $\Gamma$) But I don’t really see any way to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Triangle ABC]

Draw $AO$ and extend it to meet the circumcircle at $E$. Next, draw $IE$ and extend it to meet the circle again at $K$. $\angle AKI$ will be $90^{\circ}$.$AI$, when extended, will meet the circumcircle at $M$, the midpoint of arc $BC$. It is enough to prove that $\angle IMD=\angle IAE$ because if the points are colinear, then $\angle IMD=\angle IMK=\angle IAE$. Draw the line $IO$ and let it intersect the circle at points $P$ and $Q$.

If the circumradius is $R$ and the distance between the circumcentre and incentre is $d$, then, notice that, $AI\cdot IM=PI\cdot IQ=R^{2}-d^{2}$. Now, if the inradius is $r$, then, by Euler's Theorem, $AI\cdot IM=2Rr$. Rearranging this a bit gives, $\frac{AI}{AE}=\frac{ID}{IM}$. Also, observe that, in $\triangle AIE$ and $\triangle IDM$,$\angle DIM=\angle IAE$. Equipped with the ratio derived earlier, $\triangle AIE\sim \triangle IDM$ and thereafter $\angle IMD=\angle AEI$.